# MongoDB | Problem inserting embedded documents into document

Tags: mongodb, python

I am trying to insert data in a nested format.

A snippet of my models (there are many, many more):

```
class LifetimeMode(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    meta = {'collection': 'lifetime_mode'}
    career = db.EmbeddedDocumentField(GameModeData)
    war = db.EmbeddedDocumentField(GameModeData)
    sd = db.EmbeddedDocumentField(GameModeData)
    dom = db.EmbeddedDocumentField(GameModeData)

class LifetimeData(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    meta = {'collection': 'lifetime_data'}
    mode = db.EmbeddedDocumentField(LifetimeMode)

class UserData(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    meta = {'collection': 'user_data'}
    timestamp = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    type = db.StringField()
    level = db.IntField()
    lifetime = db.EmbeddedDocumentField(LifetimeData)

class User(db.Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'user'}
    public_id = db.UUIDField()
    gamer_id = db.StringField()
    user_data = db.EmbeddedDocumentField(UserData)
```

When I try to create my database with dummy data I am running into an issue I cannot solve. I grab my data from an external API.

```
lt_mode_data = data['lifetime']['mode'] # << This is the API returned data
for mode, mode_data in lt_mode_data.items():
    game_mode_data = GameModeData()
    lifetime_mode = LifetimeMode()
    json_data = json.dumps(mode_data['properties'])
    lifetime_mode[mode] = game_mode_data.from_json(json_data)
```

The problem is that only the final mode is added, as if each modes data gets added but is then overwritten by the next.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I changed the code to the following:

```
lt_mode_data = data['lifetime']['mode']
    mode_dict = {}
    game_mode_data = GameModeData()
    lifetime_mode = LifetimeMode()
    for index, (mode, mode_data) in enumerate(lt_mode_data.items()):
        mode_dict[mode] = mode_data['properties']
    lifetime_mode = lifetime_mode.from_json(game_mode_data.from_json(json.dumps(mode_dict)).to_json())
```